# How to change title of Git terminal in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash, titlebar

I work in Windows 10 and usually I have up to 5 CMD windows open. I work this way because I need to run the same application with different data and keep monitoring if any exception is thrown.

I set a number as the window's title (using the `title` command) instead of the default text, in order to easily identify which window I'm working in and be able to identify and change between them using `Alt+Tab` ([an example of how I work with my CMD windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxpj0.png))

Recently I started to use Git and I really like the Git Bash terminal for Windows. I would like to work with Git Bash terminal the same way I work with CMD windows, but I can't find any way to change the window title. I searched a bit and found [these instructions](https://alanbarber.com/2015/12/30/how-to-customize-the-git-for-windows-bash-shell-prompt/) and some others (that I can't paste because I'm not allowed to post more than two links yet), but it seems to work only by setting a different default title. I'd like to change the window title to any custom text I choose, at any moment.

Is this possible?  Is there a command like `title` available for Git Bash?

Comment: In standard Bash you can write `echo -ne "\e]0;YOUR TITLE HERE\a"`  - not sure if git bash is the same

Comment: In Git-Bash command above sets title for 1-2 secs and then it is changed back to default

Comment: @M.M's suggestion is working well these days. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022, unfortunately.

Comment: @Volker the accepted answer may work for you, if you want to give it a try. It's still working for me nowadays. It's more cumbersome than a single line, but works.

Comment: @Volker , I just accepted a simpler answer, in case you want to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to change the title text to anything you want.
create a title.sh script somewhere on your system like in C:\bin that has the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
export TITLEPREFIX="$*"
```

Add the following to your .bashrc file in your home directory.

```
alias title='. /c/bin/title.sh'
```

Now open a git bash window.
You can now type:

```
title my title
```

and your title will start with the title you provided to the title alias.

Comment: Wow. So simple, yet so useful. Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 19):

A simple option is `echo -ne "\e]0;YOUR TITLE HERE\a"`.

Comment: `# title "title of Git Bash window"`
`title() { echo -ne "\e]0;$1\a"; }`

Comment: @Robyte I beg to differ. I have been using this command for many years. I would suggest you review the definition of the PS1 environment variable in your bash initialization files.

Answer (score 17):

This thread is a few months old. But I think an alternative will be helpful

You can add following line to .bashrc file in your user profile folder

```
export TITLEPREFIX="Git Bash"
```

where you want **Git bash** to be your title prefix. This is user specific change. So if a machine is used by multiple users with their own logins, everyone can customize their own title.

Comment: Now, how does one get this to work when passing an argument to `git-bash.exe`? For example: `git-bash.exe -c "export TITLEPREFIX=\"Test\" && sleep 5"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

You were on the right track with [this link](https://alanbarber.com/2015/12/30/how-to-customize-the-git-for-windows-bash-shell-prompt/)

If you modify the `git-prompt.sh` script a bit (for me, this is located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`), you can make the title anything you want.

***Note: You will need to run VS Code, Notepad++ or similar as administrator to write back to this directory.***

First, save a backup of `git-prompt.sh` (like `git-prompt.backup.sh`), then modify the start of `git-prompt.sh` as follows:

```bash
if test -z "$GITTITLEPREFIX" # if not empty
then
    GITTITLEPREFIX="Git-Bash => " # prefix that will have current pwd appended after it
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    if test -n "$GITTITLE"
    then   ##### Set window title directly to GITTITLE if not empty
        PS1='\[\033]0;$GITTITLE\007\]' 
    else   ##### Set window title to GITTITLE PREFIX plus the PWD
        PS1='\[\033]0;$GITTITLEPREFIX${PWD//]^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]' 
    fi
fi
###### Leave the rest of the file the same
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'
###### Etc.
```

This will first check if GITTITLEPREFIX is empty, and if not, it will set it to "Git-Bash => " similar to in the linked article.  This will have the current path appended after it, so if you want "1 : $PWD", then set GITTITLEPREFIX to "1 : " like this:

```
GITTITLEPREFIX="1 : "
```

Otherwise, you can set GITTITLE to any non-empty value, and then the entire title will be set exactly to the contents of GITTITLE (no PWD appended), so if you just want "1", use this:

```
GITTITLE="1"
```

Then run the script.  With my path, I did it like this:

```
. "/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh"
```

and the title should change.  Of course, you can alias this or make a separate script from it in a location that is in the path so running it is much simpler, and the title could just be an argument. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Works for me, not exactly a `title` command as I expected, but perfect for what I need, and as you say, I'll try different options using the script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Found a bug here - the first `if..fi` construct should be checking for empty (or running the default assignment on `else` rather than `then`).  I fixed this by modifying the `-n` to a `-z` for the `test` flag.

Comment: Uhm.. That must be why it didn't work in the first time. At the end, following your indications, I made my own modifications to the script to pass the title as a parameter. As I said, thanks!

Comment: @IsidroSerranoPineda You could post your final script as another answer that could help others that are looking for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @LightCC, I don't mean any harm to your reputation by unaccepting your answer, I just found a simpler answer and I think it deserves to be marked as answer.

Answer (score 3):

In JSON setting write for Git Console:

```
"name": "Git Bash",
"tabTitle": "Git Bash",
"suppressApplicationTitle": true
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but if it helps someone, you can set the title prefix simply by changing the TITLEPREFIX env variable:

TITLEPREFIX=YourTitlePrefix

Comment: that works well..

Answer (score 2):

I solved my question making very little modifications to the script. 
The first one, to pass the name I want for the window, I added the variable `name=$1` and set it in the title variable:

```
name=$1
PS1='\[\033]0;$name\007\]' # set window title
```

The second one, as recommended [here](https://alanbarber.com/2015/12/30/how-to-customize-the-git-for-windows-bash-shell-prompt/), I commented the next lines:

```
#PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
#PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
```

The final code is below:

```
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi
name=$1
PS1='\[\033]0;$name\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
#PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
#PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
    if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
    then
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
    fi
fi
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"               # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc
```

Temporally I made a copy of the script and pasted it on C:, to execute it easily every time I need to change the title, according to my path, as as follows:
`$ . /c/changename.sh`

I'm still learning about scripting so I could be able to set an alias. As @LightCC said, "I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader..."

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
export MYTITLE=abcd; export PS1=$(echo $PS1 | sed -r "s/(0;).*?(\\\\007)/\1$MYTITLE\2/")
```

It find regular expression for title and replace it with `$MYTITLE`.
I could be wrong but I assume title is something between `0;` and `\007` in `$PS1`. It work for me.

Or you could add next function to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`)

```
ttt() {
        # change title in gitbash
        export PS1=$(echo $PS1 | sed -r "s/(0;).*?(\\\\007)/\1$1\2/")
}
```

and then anytime use `ttt "new title"`

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old but if anyone is still looking for a solution,

1. Terminal> Settings> Tab title>
2. Change it to anything you would like then scroll down.
3. Advanced> Suppress title changes> Turn on> Save

I hope this helps you!

Comment: what application is this for? mine says "mintty 3.6.4" and there is only "Options" in the window bar context menu (and funnily: copy title). it doesn't support tabs afaik, and there is no title option in the options.

Comment: This is specifically for Windows Terminal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/